# sharepoint page edit ribbon how to fix to not be hiddin

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, 2019

we have SharePoint 2019

when admin try to edit page ribbon is showing but when sliding to down of page it get hide

how to keep it always showing while edit page and slide on the page

Comment: The ribbon should be frozen when scrolling - sounds like you have any custom CSS/solution that breaks it? Is it only for a single page/site?

Comment: in all pages same problem

Comment: Are you using a custom master page?

Comment: yes masterpage is costumed from design team

Comment: Then there is probably some part of the customization that overrides the ribbons default functionality to remain frozen. Guess you need to reach out to your design team to debug and track down the error to find a solution.